# How to compare two different tables find out the rest of records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two different tables, called tableA and tableB, I want to compare these two tables.
The structures as following:

tableA use following query has 511 records

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM tableA
  WHERE [ID_NAME] = 'a06'
```

tableB use following query has 507 records

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM tableB
  where [FILENAME] like 'a06%' and [TIME] = '201705'
```

I wanna to compare these two tables use the common column PNO, I use the following query can find these two tables intersection(507 records):

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM tableA
WHERE PNO IN (SELECT PNO
                 FROM tableB
                 WHERE [FILENAME] like 'a06%' and [TIME] = '201705')
```

Now, what should I do ? I think use left join can find out the rest of 4 records, but I tried many times it still didn't work, please help me.

Comment: Which database engine do you use? Edit your tags.

Comment: sql server I assume?..

Comment: Hello @MichaelO. I just change my tags

Comment: @VaoTsun , Yes I use sql server

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in many ways, and using `left join` is one of them:

```
SELECT  ta.*
FROM    tableA ta
LEFT JOIN
        tableB tb
ON      ta.[PNO] = tb.[PNO] and
        ta.[ID_NAME] = 'a06' and
        tb.[FILENAME] like 'a06%' and tb.[TIME] = '201705'
WHERE   tb.[PNO] is null
```

Note that the conditions that were previously in your `WHERE` clauses are now moved in the join condition; that's because the `LEFT JOIN` will assign `NULL` values to the rows that aren't matched, but if you filter on some of the fields of the right table this feature gets lost.

**Edit**

Another option is following the same path you were using to find the intersection, just adding the condition on `tableA` and changing `IN` to `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableA
WHERE   PNO NOT IN (
            SELECT  PNO
            FROM    tableB
            WHERE   [FILENAME] like 'a06%' and [TIME] = '201705'
        ) and
        [ID_NAME] = 'a06'
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically You want to do A-B

```
   SELECT *
    FROM tableA t1
    WHERE t1.PNO Not IN (SELECT PNO
                     FROM tableB
                     WHERE [FILENAME] like 'a06%' and [TIME] = '201705')
```

> OR

```
   SELECT *
    FROM tableA t1
    WHERE t1.PNO EXCEPT
      (SELECT *
       FROM tableB
             WHERE [FILENAME] like 'a06%' and [TIME] = '201705')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on SQL Server 2008 +

```
SELECT PNO FROM TABLE A 
INTO #TEMP_A
EXCEPT
SELECT PNO FROM TABLE B
```

Will return the PNO that are not in both tables

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableA
WHERE   PNO (Select PNO from #TEMP_A)
```

Will return all rows in table A with the missing PNO.